# Include Python in Qt Creator

Tags: python, c++, qt

I am trying to embed python in my c++ code in my qt project as per [this tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/extending/embedding.html). I am now getting this error code: "error: undefined reference to `_imp__Py_Initialize'"

Before this, I had the same problem in CodeBlocks and fixed it by with these additional arguments "-IC:\Python27\include\ -IC:\Python27\libs\" and "C:\Python27\libs\python27.lib"

Adding the same commands to my .pro file as such:

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -Wall -fexceptions -g -IC:\Python27\include\ -IC:\Python27\libs\ C:\Python27\libs\python27.lib
```

Allows me to import python.h but nothing more.

I know that questions like this have been posted before, and they helped me get running in CodeBlocks, but the same information dosent apply to Qt, or I am implementing it wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `LIBS` configuration variable to add an external library to your project. Something like this:

```
LIBS += C:\Python27\libs\python27.lib
```

You can find more info [in documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-variable-reference.html#libs).

Comment: I'm afraid that this does not help,  the error still persists.

Comment: I'm sorry, -L prefix was wrong. It's used for adding a new library path.

Answer (score 2):

To build on HeyYO's answer, the .pro arguments to fix the problem are:

```
INCLUDEPATH = c:\Python27\include\ c:\Python27\libs\

LIBS += C:\Python27\libs\python27.lib

QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += C:\Python27\libs\python27.lib
```